# How to assign values to BehaviourID for AutoComplete Extender inside Gridview

Tags: asp.net, ajax

How to assign values to BehaviourID for AutoComplete Extender inside Gridview

for example, i am binding ID in Gridview hidden Field and also i am having textbox with AUtocompleteExtender In this case how can i assign that hidden field value to Behaviour ID of AutoComplete Extender.

Comment: Show us What have you tried ?

Comment: aspx       <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtpolststatus" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="Acepolststatus" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtpolststatus" CompletionInterval="50"
                                     UseContextKey="true" EnableCaching="false" MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServiceMethod="GetPoLStstatus" BehaviorID='<%# Eval("ID") %>' >
                                </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>